# Customzie 'Duplicate Line' shortcut in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

- How to customize 'Duplicate Lines' shortcut in dbeaver Application?
- Sometime in application predefined shortcut conflict/overlapping with other shortcut's!
- To overcome this issue, We can follow below approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- By clicking on Menu: Window -> Preference -> User Interface -> Keys -> Search: 'Duplicate Lines'
- Update/Enter Your choice hot key in Binding field.
- Click on 'Apply and Close'

By this we can customize 'Duplicate Lines' shortcut :)